# Open datasets of lottery winning numbers

Tags: data-request, sports, games

I saw only paid feeds for lotteries games. Also would be great to get dataset of virtual betting games

Comment: You want a list of lotteries (games) or list of the lotteries' winning numbers?

Comment: I'd like to find list of the lotteries `winning numbers`

Comment: Are you interested in international sets or just US?

Comment: It would be great to get all sort of possible international + US. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

About Italian lotto you can download data from 1939 to today.

On this page: https://www.lottomatica.it/lotterie/lotto

It is in Italian, but, if you click on "**Estrazioni**" on the top left and then you search for word "**scarica**", you can download csv data.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few datasets from New York State with a list of winning numbers:

- Lottery Daily Numbers/Win-4 Winning Numbers: Beginning 1980 - https://data.ny.gov/Government-Finance/Lottery-Daily-Numbers-Win-4-Winning-Numbers-Beginn/hsys-3def
- Lottery Cash 4 Life Winning Numbers: Beginning 2014 - https://data.ny.gov/Government-Finance/Lottery-Cash-4-Life-Winning-Numbers-Beginning-2014/kwxv-fwze
- Lottery Mega Millions Winning Numbers: Beginning 2002 - https://data.ny.gov/Government-Finance/Lottery-Mega-Millions-Winning-Numbers-Beginning-20/5xaw-6ayf
- Lottery Take 5 Winning Numbers - https://data.ny.gov/Government-Finance/Lottery-Take-5-Winning-Numbers/dg63-4siq

Here is some data about different state/local government lottery programs/games from across the United States:

- CT Lottery Sales By Game - https://data.ct.gov/Government/Lottery-Sales-By-Game/n9q9-yvd6
- IL Lottery Sales by Zip Code - https://data.illinois.gov/Economics/IDOR-FY-2011-Lottery-Sales-by-Zip-Code/r9kx-zjnk
- OR Contracts related to the Lottery - https://data.oregon.gov/Revenue-Expense/Contracts-Lottery-Fiscal-Year-2013/6gby-m8wg
- IO Lottery Sales, Proceeds, and Prizes - https://data.iowa.gov/Economy/Lottery-Sales-Proceeds-and-Prizes/b9m5-qwb9